# OpenID Implementation , paid libraries?

Tags: authentication, .net, sso

Is there any paid library available for Openid implementation ,please list any paid libraries available ? **Or does Microsoft support openid implementation** ? ?

Answer (score 3):

A quick Bing search shows a few options.

http://sharepoint-live-authentication.shetabtech.com/ - Paid option

http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/ - free option

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/01/updated-adding-an-openid-claims-provider-for-ad-fs-2-0-to-extend-access-to-sharepoint-2010/ - a how-to